# when i edit in exist document it retrieve to me the old value not my edit value what should i do?

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp

when i edit in exist document it retrieve to me the old value not my edit value what should i do ?

```
BasicDBObject newDocument=new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject OldDocument=new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject upd=new BasicDBObject();
String value = request.getParameter("_id");
String name = session.getAttribute("un").toString();

System.out.println(name);

newDocument.put("un",user.getName());

OldDocument.put("name",name);

upd.put("$set",newDocument);

coll.update(OldDocument,upd);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use {new : true} option for retrieving latest updated doc

```
BasicDBObject newDocument=new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject OldDocument=new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject upd=new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject opt=new BasicDBObject();
String value = request.getParameter("_id");
String name = session.getAttribute("un").toString();

System.out.println(name);

newDocument.put("un",user.getName());

OldDocument.put("name",name);


upd.put("$set",newDocument);
opt.put("new",true);

coll.update(OldDocument,upd,opt);
```

Comment: The method update(DBObject, DBObject) in the type DBCollection is not applicable for the arguments (BasicDBObject, 
 BasicDBObject, BasicDBObject) update it can't accept the third object do you have another solution ?

Comment: yes,there is a  findAndModify in java driver ,please refer http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findAndModify-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-boolean-com.mongodb.DBObject-boolean-boolean-boolean-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-com.mongodb.WriteConcern-